# DRF Create new object and link to (but not create) it's related items (nested serializer)?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm trying to link multiple items (subdomains) to an item being created (evidence).

My form submits okay - but I'm trying to figure out the 'best' way to go about this.

[According to the docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers) I have to override the create method - but their example shows them 'creating' the related objects.

I don't want to do that. I want to just just add those related items to the piece of evidence I am creating (to create the relationship)

Here are my serializers:

```
class SubdomainSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Subdomain
        fields = [
            "id",
            "domain",
            "short_description",
            "long_description",
            "character_code",
        ]


class EvidenceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    """

    created_by = serializers.HiddenField(
        default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault()
    )
    updated_by = serializers.HiddenField(
        default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault()
    )
    absolute_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    created_by_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    updated_by_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    subdomains = SubdomainSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Evidence
        fields = "__all__"
        extra_kwargs = {
            "subdomains": {
                "error_messages": {
                    "null": "This field is required.",
                    "blank": "This field is required.",
                }
            },
        }

    def get_absolute_url(self, obj):
        return obj.get_absolute_url()

    def get_created_by_name(self, obj):
        return obj.created_by.full_name

    def get_updated_by_name(self, obj):
        return obj.updated_by.full_name

    def create(self, validated_data):
        subdomains_data = validated_data.pop("subdomains")
        evidence = Evidence.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for subdomain in subdomains_data:
            # This is where I want to add the subdomains to the evidence - not create ones - how best to accomplish that?
            Subdomain.objects.create(**subdomain)
        return evidence

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        # Add the requestor as the updater in a PATCH request
        request = self.context["request"]
        validated_data["updated_by"] = request.user
        return super().update(instance, validated_data)
```

Is there a better way to setup my serializers? Should I be doing something different to make this more achievable?

Edited to add my models:

```
class Subdomain(CreateUpdateMixin):
    """

    """

    domain = models.ForeignKey(Domain, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    short_description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    long_description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    character_code = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    proficiency_levels = models.ManyToManyField(SubdomainProficiencyLevel)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Subdomain"
        verbose_name_plural = "Subdomains"

    def __str__(self):
        """Unicode representation of Subdomain."""
        return f"{self.character_code}"

class Evidence(CreateUpdateMixin, CreateUpdateUserMixin, SoftDeletionModel):
    """

    """

    subdomains = models.ManyToManyField(Subdomain, related_name="evidences")
    evaluation = models.ForeignKey(
        Evaluation, related_name="evidences", on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-created_at"]
        verbose_name = "Evidence"
        verbose_name_plural = "Evidence"

    def __str__(self):
        """Unicode representation of Evidence."""
        return f"{self.subdomain} : {self.comments}"

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Return absolute url for Evidence."""
        return reverse("evidence-detail", args=[str(self.id)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you want to set the `subdomain` ForeignKey to the new created `evidence`.
For that, you just have to retrieve the subdomain and update his evidence field like this :

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    subdomains_data = validated_data.pop("subdomains")
    evidence = Evidence.objects.create(**validated_data)
    for subdomain in subdomains_data:
        # Retrieve the subdomain and update the evidence attribute
        sub_id = subdomain['id']
        sub = Subdomain.objects.get(id=sub_id)
        sub.evidence = evidence
        sub.save()
    return evidence
```

**NB :** I use the default inverse ForeignKey relationship : `sub.evidence`

Comment: So the `subdomain['id']`, while existing in the POST data, never makes it to the create method - which is by design apparently. You have to include `extra_kwargs = {"id": {"read_only": False}}` to get the ID to come across from the POST data, but that seems awfully hacky to me.